# ContentPlaceHolder outside form in ASP.NET 4 / Visual Studio 2008 supported?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, master-pages, asp.net-4.0

When master pages were first introduced, you could create a ContentPlaceHolder within the header element.  This actually worked in the compiler, but not in the IDE, so I wasn’t sure if it was a bug or supported or what.  So I dynamically created things like scripts and styles in PageLoad, which worked well for everything, but was a little more effort than just using the head element without master pages.

I just noticed ASP.NET 4/ Visual Studio 2008 does not have this problem, ContentPlaceHolders work fine even outside the  element.  Does anyone know if this is supported, working, usable and good practice going forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works fine. You can put ContentPlaceHolders in the head or the body, I've been doing it for ages.

In fact in VS2010, when you create a new master page it automatically puts a ContentPlaceHolder block in the file. So I would assume from this that it **is** supported. Check:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

Some links that may be worth a read (although I've found nothing that confirms official support):

[ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

[The ContentPlaceHolder – Not Just For Content](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/04/11/the-contentplaceholder-not-just-for-content.aspx)